# echo <body> doesn't activate jquery script

Tags: php, jquery

So I have a url from where I extract the data with **extracthtml.php**:

```
<?php
    include("simple_html_dom.php");
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    $body = $html->find('body', 0);
    $title = $html->find('title', 0);
    echo $title;
    echo $body;
?>
<script src="extract.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then with jquery I put a box around all the p elements to see if this communication works (test, am going to add more css manipulation later). My jquery starts with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('p').css("border", "2px solid black");
});
```

Im guessing document.ready is the problem, because there appears to be no boxes around the p elements.

Comment: Where are you echo'ing the jquery? Inside the $body?

Comment: im echoing to the browser....the jquery script runs after the php

Comment: <?php ?>                                                         <script src="extract.js" type="text/javascript"></script>                  like so

Comment: So...you are adding a script tag to the page after you close the </body>?

Comment: the script is in extracthtml.php...then it sends to a jquery script

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show us exactly how you are adding the jquery to the page in relation to the above code? I'm having trouble following it, but I suspect you are adding it in a way that the browser won't run it.

Comment: when I echo the ENTIRE html, this works. But only echoing the body: does not work

Comment: Can you post the actual output of this script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are echoing the jquery line to the browser after you close the page.

Since you echo the $body first, I would guess your page ends up looking something like this:

```
<body>
    ...
</body>
<script>
    jquery here
</script>
```

Without seeing your page output this is only a guess, but if it is correct the browser will not run any code after the `</body>` tag. I would advise checking the source of your output to see if this is the case.

Comment: the script ends up inside the body tag ....im just wondering why it works when all of the html is loaded (echo $html)...and not just body

Comment: Could be a browser issue. Have you tried opening the javascript console for the browser you are using and checking for errors?

Comment: Any change you can link to the page? It would be a lot easier if I could see the source.

Comment: Fixed: 
 

    echo '<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>';

inside the php file